# phpmyadmin not found after install on VPS

Tags: server, mysql, php, phpmyadmin, vps

Hello i installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu 20.04, i did all the updates,
when i type on Google Chrome IP/phpmyadmin says

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at

EDIT: now i am getting this **Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at**

Comment: i followed these guides https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Could you try replacing your IP adress by `localhost`or `127.0.0.1` ?  (If you run on the machine, of course)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: ok i fixed it somehow, what is this error guys?ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client



The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
Open new phpMyAdmin window
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.